# Issue with clean install of Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I used the option of "something else" for the clean installation of Ubuntu. My partition looks something like this:

[image]

However when I reboot my computer, I get a grub terminal and nothing else. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is relevant to your question. but this is how I partition in any linux distro.

```
sdx1 ext4 30gb /root

sdx2 swap (same size with my ram) /swap

sdx3 ext4 100gb or the remaining space /home

sdx4 ntfs (remaining space-optional if I need a backup or I need to go back in ms without destroying my backup files ) /
```